# Copying a subscribed database to the publisher server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I have two servers. 

I have installed a merge replication in the publisher (Server A) and I have added two subscriptions with the same database name.

- One on the publisher itself and the seconde one on the subscriber (Server B).So far so good. The replication is working well.
I wanted to delete the subscibed database on the publisher (Server A) and replace it by a copy of subscribed database from Server B.


I thought the publisher will continue synchronizing on the newly attached database, but unfortunately, it didn't work as expected, it started aplying snapshot etc.. instead.

Is there anything to modify on the the copied database to make the publisher reconise it as the deleted one and continues synchronizing  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything to modify on the the copied database to make the publisher reconise it as the deleted one and continues synchronizing ?

This is not possible. The subscription is now broken and should be removed / recreated per your requirements. There are unique identifiers in play beyond the DB name which is why it didn't work as you intended.

Comment: yes I think so, but i don't know,I remember I've tried this before on small sample DBs and it worked fine! but when I moved to the real DBs it didn't work